# Failing to load gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

I get an error when I load the gtsummary package. Any ideas?

````
 namespace ‘cli’ 3.1.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.1.1 is required```
````

Comment: What is your `packageVersion('cli')` ? As error message suggests you need at least 3.1.1 and may need to update `cli` package.

Comment: try restarting R. you probably already updated `cli` but cannot be unloaded because of dependencies with other namespaces

Comment: I actually updated the cli and the problem was sorted.

Comment: @RonakShah, hey I am receiving the same problem with the gtsummary package, how do I update the cli package?

Comment: install.packages("cli")